# LibreOffice Base Form Error with PostgreSQL Autogenerated UUID Primary Key

Tags: postgresql, uuid, libreoffice-base

I have a PostgreSQL 9.5 back-end and with LibreOffice Base v 5.1.3.2 (x64) I am trying to create some data entry forms for various tables all with 1:many relationships.  These tables all have UUID auto generated primary-keys.

LibreOffice does not like these PostgreSQL auto generated primary keys.  It keeps giving me errors when I try to create a new record, sometimes when I try to edit a new record and won't give me access to the sub-form after I try to create a new parent record.  Its like it cannot commit the records and isn't getting an "update" from PSQL upon a new create record.

I have discovered on the net that this is a known problem with all PostgreSQL auto generated PKEYS (UUID, SERIAL, etc) and the LibreOffice native PostgreSQL drivers.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Phil

Comment: Can you add rows directly into the table view (i.e. not in a form)?

Comment: Yes I can add a record in the table view...sort of.  If I create a new record in the table view the uuid doesn't appear until I close the table view and re-open it.  Also if I create new record, move to another record, then return to the newly created record i cannot edit it.  But if I then close the table view and re-open it I can then edit it.  That is why I think there is an update/commit type problem.

Comment: If you have some familiarity with macros you could experiment with, from inside the form, issuing table row update and form refresh commands to see if that helps as a workaround.  Otherwise it sounds like this bug may prevent any use of Base with UUID keys.

Comment: I added a push button and put the following code behind it. Sub pgsql_update_record_main( event as Object )
 dim myForm as Object
 
 myForm = event.Source.Model.Parent
 myForm.insertRow()
rem myForm.reload()
End Sub
The reload just bounced me to the previous record and the insertrow() command produced the following error: Error code: 1

pq_driver: [PGRES_FATAL_ERROR]ERROR:  invalid input syntax for uuid: "public.uuid_generate_v1()"
LINE 1: ...m_cert" WHERE ( "gobs_data"."rm_cert"."rm_uuid" = 'public.uu..